# All sets of rational numbers such that $p,q\in S\Rightarrow p+3nq\in S$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Let $S$ be a nonempty set of rational numbers ($S\subset \mathbb{Q}$) such that :
$$\begin{align}\forall p,q\in S\ \forall n\in \mathbb{Z}&& p+3nq\in S\end{align}$$

can someone help me to characterize all such sets.

In fact for similar problems like the sets of rational numbers such that if $p,q \in A$ then $p+nq\in A$ for every integer $n$ we can easily prove that $A$ is an additive subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$,and we know the form of such sets, but for this question I can't find any link.

Any suggestion, idea, method will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

If we "seed" $S$ with one number $a \in \mathbb{Q}$, we are then required to have all number of the form $(3k+1)a \in S$. Combinations of these under the rules will lead to another number of this form.

If we then introduce another number $b$ not of this form, $S$ will extend to consist of all combinations of these forms with $a$ or $b$ as the single term,  $(a+3ma+3nb)$ and $(b+3ma+3nb)$.

It seems that the effect of this combination is to effectively reduce the two seeds to small multiples of $ \gcd(a,b)$ - that is, given $c=\gcd(a,b), S$ is formed of all $kc,$ where $k \equiv \{\frac{a}{c},\frac{b}{c}\} \bmod 3$.

Comment: @Elaqqad updated a little.

Comment: thanks, Using this, if we consider that the gcd of all elements of $S$ is $d$ and we denote by $R=\{a_i/d\mod 3\, :\,  a\in S\}$ can we prove that : $S=(R+3Z)d$?